EF8 - The skip navigation 'FurnitureItem.HandItems' doesn't have a foreign key associated with it
Full Error

System.InvalidOperationException: The skip navigation 'FurnitureItem.HandItems' doesn't have a foreign key associated with it. Every skip navigation must have a configured foreign key.
Setup

Setup:
modelBuilder.Entity<FurnitureItem>()
    .HasMany(c => c.HandItems)
    .WithMany(x => x.FurnitureItems)
    .UsingEntity("furniture_hand_items",
        l => l.HasOne(typeof(FurnitureItem)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("furniture_item_id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(FurnitureItem.Id)),
        r => r.HasOne(typeof(HandItem)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("hand_item_id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(HandItem.Id)),
        j => j.HasKey("furniture_item_id", "hand_item_id"));

Entities:
public class FurnitureItem
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public ICollection<HandItem> HandItems { get; init; } = [];
}

public class HandItem
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FurnitureItem> FurnitureItems { get; init; } = [];
}

Tables:

furniture_items
hand_items
furniture_hand_items (bridge table)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You've got the right/left switched on the navigation properties. Try:
        modelBuilder.Entity<FurnitureItem>()
                    .HasMany(c => c.HandItems)
                    .WithMany(x => x.FurnitureItems)
                    .UsingEntity("furniture_hand_items"
                    , r => r.HasOne(typeof(HandItem)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("hand_item_id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(HandItem.Id))
                    , l => l.HasOne(typeof(FurnitureItem)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("furniture_item_id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(FurnitureItem.Id))
                    , j => j.HasKey("furniture_item_id", "hand_item_id"));

